# How to include maps in Jupyter notebook HTML export?

Tags: python, arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook

I'm running the 1.4.2 version of the ArcGIS Python API. In a Jupyter Notebook, I create a map like:

```
lowes = "Arkansas USA Lowe's"
lowes_map = gis.map("AR, US", 6)
lowes_map
```

...and get my output. I then geocode some points and plot them:

[image]

All is great there, but when I export to HTML, my map isn't there (this particular notebook has maybe 8 maps and none of them get exported to HTML):

[image]

If I display Portal items in my notebook, they get included in the HTML export. Also, all the code samples on the Python API docs have maps in them (such as [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/using-the-gis/#Embedded-maps-in-Jupyter-notebooks)), so I'm thinking I'm just missing something?

Anyone know how to get maps to render in HTML export?

Answer (score 1):

```
map.embed(output_in_cell=True, set_as_preview=False)
```

Solved it for me, hope it does for you too.
Check this for more info:
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/part5-saving-updating-and-embedding-map-widget/#embedding-a-live-map